# Position relative and absolute with margin bottom 0

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to put image number 3 at the bottom of the page, but it doesn't work. I used position fix and sticky too but it doesn't work too.

```css
.boxes {
    position: absolute;
}
.downa {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
}
.topa {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <center>
    <img class="topa" height="50" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/1/Y/3/j/Z/blue-number-1-md.png" width="50" />
  </center>
  
  <center>
    <img class="downa" height="50" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/g/b/d/Y/s/2/blue-number-3-md.png" width="50" />
  </center>
</div>
```

How can I put image number 3 at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Looks "down" to me. What's the problem?

Comment: It's not down of page, it's actually down of number 1 not in the down bottom 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the parent of the "3" image (like ".foo") than impose the "fixed" propriety:

```
.boxes{
    position:absolute;
    }
    .downa{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0px;
    }
    .topa{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    }
.foo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0
}

<div class="boxes">
<center>
<img class="topa" height="50" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/1/Y/3/j/Z/blue-number-1-md.png" width="50" />
</center>
<center class="foo">
<img class="downa" height="50" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/g/b/d/Y/s/2/blue-number-3-md.png" width="50" />
</center>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6Lg9tns/

I am supposing you are looking for a sticky footer; if you want a positioning based on the actual height of parent element only; you should use Javascript (or, more likely JQuery) to check the actual size of the element (if dynamic) and set the proper value for positioning...

Comment: Yes done. Could you please explain it to me why shall I use another class to make it in the down of page? why it doesn't work with class downa?? Thank you bro

Comment: Cause the downa is the class of the image that's the child of another tag; so, moving the parent, you move the child too. That's like to say: if i want to move a box that's INSIDE another larger box, i have to move the larger and the smaller together.

Comment: Alright.  Thank you for your answer and help. merci beaucoup :)

Comment: De rien mon ami, je vous en prie!

Answer (score 0):

Try this    .boxes{position:relative;}    .downa{position:absolute; bottom:0;left:0px; }    .topa{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}